# Atom - Terrafrom

Tags: terraform, atom-editor

Using newest version of Atom 1.40.1 on Win-10.

Very new to Atom - but I did get the Cloud Formation thing working. Loved it.

Now trying to use it for Terraform.
I have installed the suggested package- atom-beautify, linter, linter-terraform-syntax, language-terraform. But cant get anything going at all. 
I tried creating a new project and new .tf file. That did not do the trick - no snippets no nothing at all. Likely startup issues - docs don't help.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier was getting an error, that was due to Terraform not in correct PATH. After sorting that out - it started working, *at least sort of*. No useful snippets or auto complete but general formatting color highlighting only (yet)